# JSF editions and Ajax server-side processing

Tags: ajax, jsf, omnifaces

Will the new JSF 4.0 be free of the full view getting rebuild on server side after each ajax request?
This rebuild is very time consuming on pages with many components.

Or exists a way to avoid building the whole view after Ajax call?
Maybe cache components on the server side, they will not change by Ajax?

I was looking for the solution in Omnifaces, tried with o:cache, but does not work. Every time after ajax request all components are rebuild.

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuild"? If you execute AJAX calls using the `f:ajax` behavior in JSF, which is available since JSF 2.0, then such calls cause processing and rendering only of a specific component to which this behavior is attached. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro007.htm#GKNOJ

Comment: JSF rebuilds the entire component tree (on the sever side only) in restore view phase. And evaluates EL expressions for all components, even if Ajax call does not change any components. As described in:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175131/jsf-ajax-performance-issue-when-using-a-lot-of-components).

Comment: I wouldn’t trust the answer with 1 upvote stating something like that, especially if it contradicts the documentation. Please check other comments to that question — there’s a strong evidence that this is just a an issue with a particular JSF implementation, not with JSF itself.

Comment: This is not a JSF version issue as much as it is a implementation issue. Please take a look at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/2498. MyFaces also has some parameters you can tweak to modify it's behavior.